# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Forbidden [403] Errors [Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]]

Tags: google-calendar-api

Caveat: This is not strictly a coding question but it is definitely a technical question about Google Calendar API v3 and their support documentation refers to stackoverflow for technical questions.

The error response in the title is the result of trying to delete an event with API3.  I do not believe it is a coding issue as our clients are interacting with about 3000 Google calendars and only about 50 of them have encountered this issue.  The other 98% or so are deleting events without issue.

I do not know how to replicate this error and my ability to tinker with the production calendars of paying customers and their calendar authorizations is limited.

Hence this question.  Do you have any insight what might be causing this error or what I might do with my developer's calendar to replicate it?

I have changed passwords, deleted events and changed sharing permissions on shared calendars and they throw different errors.

Answer (score 0):

And since I didn't see this error associated with the explanation I found, I will post this Q&A style to hopefully help someone else who encounters it.

I was able to replicate the issue by reassigning the event to a different calendar inside of Google calendar.  Our application was trying to modify/delete the event with the right event id but the wrong calendar id.  Now I have a clue how code should respond to this error.

If you know of any pitfalls with this premise, please let me know!